# Saving the output of ADB install into a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, adb

I was just wondering if there is a way to save the output of the command adb install APK into a text file.

I have tried the normal way of
`adb install apk > output.txt`.
This only saves "Performing Streamed Install" part of the installation process.

I want to get the next output of this command where it shows me whether it has Succeeded in installing the APK or not

Other solutions that I have tried includes

```bash
FOR /f 'tokens=*' %%G IN (adb install APK) DO echo %%G > output.txt
```

This command still only shows me "Performing Streamed Install" text.

An example of what I want would be the results

`adb: failed to install 55bc5294aaf6e7ec291f24791d444af2a91a7c996c06f72b84dfc5dc99abce8d.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]`

or
`Success`

saved into a text file

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Try `... >output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: ... or maybe ```@(For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('adb.exe install APK 2^>^&1') Do @Echo %%G) 1>"output.txt"```

Comment: You only redirect stdout to the file, but the other message are written to stderr which you have not redirected.